# SQL-Injection: is it possible to have modifying subquery of select?

Tags: mysql, security, sql-injection

Is it possible to have a subquery modifying the database in a SELECT-Query? The relevant database is a mysql database.

Some more details:
The relevant query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $x
```

And the variable $x can be replaced with anything. The only restriction is, that the query is executed via php's mysql_query(), which prevents the execution of multiple subsequent queries. In that case, modifying the DB would be easy, simply set

```
$x = "42; DROP TABLE foo;"
```

Comment: Create an SQL user that only has read privileges, and run the query on that user. Simple and secure.

Comment: Thats the thing i intend to to - i was just looking for a way to prove that the site using such queries is insecure (which it obviously is...)

Comment: Your updated example doesn't show a [sub-query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) in the technical sense of the term... are you asking about multiple commands instead of specifically sub-queries?

Comment: No, the updated example shows the way it does *not* work, but what I have already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

`mysql_query()` only prevents multiple queries in versions of MySql earlier than 5.0.  [MySql 5.0 or later will allow multiple commands separated by `;` when using `mysql_query()`.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html)

So, yes, [a SQL Injection attack](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) is capable of doing whatever commands the login used to connect to the database has permissions to do.

If you connect using admin privileges, the attack could do essentially any possible modification to your database.

For example, say that you concatenate the $email value to the SQL string below:

```
"SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name
  FROM members
 WHERE email = '" + $email + "'"
```

But lets say that the $email value contains the string:

```
        x';INSERT INTO members ('email','passwd','login_id','full_name') 
        VALUES ('steve@unixwiz.net','hello','steve','Steve Friedl');--
```

You end up with the following statement:

```
SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name
  FROM members
 WHERE email = 'x';
        INSERT INTO members ('email','passwd','login_id','full_name') 
        VALUES ('steve@unixwiz.net','hello','steve','Steve Friedl');--';
```

Even if modifications weren't allowed by the login that you're using to connect to the database, SQL Injection attacks could be used to scrape every bit of data our of your database...

It's definitely recommended that you protect yourself by using some form of parameterized queries in your client application.

Comment: I know of sql-injections, but the obvious way with finishing the current query by simply adding a ';' and adding another statement does not work here - see my edit from above.

Answer (score 1):

It would be conceivably possible to have a subquery modify the database in a  `SELECT` statement.  As long as the API used permits multiple queries per statement, the following example would work:

Consider `injectvar` populated with the following bad data. Its purpose was to be used in a subquery `WHERE` clause:

```
injectvar = "0); DELETE FROM tbl; --"

SELECT a, b
FROM tbl 
WHERE a IN (SELECT DISTINCT c FROM tbl2 WHERE d = injectvar)
```

Results in :

```
SELECT a, b
FROM tbl 
WHERE a IN (SELECT DISTINCT c FROM tbl2 WHERE d = 0); DELETE FROM tbl; --)
```

As long as the injectable code can form a valid SQL statement, you will have trouble. In this case, it requires closing the subquery with a `)` and the attacker would need some knowledge of your query structure. It would be more difficult to blindly try injection attacks, but if a robot is doing that it is entirely possible.

Comment: A query like yours was my idea, too. However, such queries always produce syntax errors, beginning at the "DELETE".

Comment: @Jost See the change above. You're correct that the `1=1 AND DELETE` won't work in MySQL the way it will in Oracle or SQL Server. However if the API used allows multiple queries, the above will work now, by terminating the first statement with `;`

Comment: @Jost The above wouldn't work in a standard PHP `mysql_query()` for example, where only one query is executed (up to first `;`) however.

Answer (score -3):

I see no point in asking such kind of questions.

So what if you get a negative answer regarding one particular injection method?
You consider yourself safe then?  If injection is possible - it doesn't matter which one it is. One or another - it doesn't matter. Reading can be no less disastrous than writing.

Comment: I didn't ask this qustion to feel save - I know how to prevent SQL-injections. The purpose of this question is to be able to demonstrate a vulnerability on a particular site to a customer.

Comment: You can demonstrate a vulnerability without dropping table as well. THAT is the point.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel  I believe I mentioned what you're saying in the summary of my answer... "Even if modifications weren't allowed by the login that you're using to connect to the database, SQL Injection attacks could be used to scrape every bit of data out of your database..."